# Reading a snippet of 15th century handwriting in Latin

Tags: medieval-latin, orthography, vulgata

The [Lilly library](http://www.indiana.edu/~liblilly/) has a Gutenberg bible on display and the page that it is open to varies.  This week the page had a marginal comment in it, which is unusual for this particular copy, and I was hoping to understand what is written there.  The image is given below.  Note that the page has been cut and it's likely that some of the writing is missing on the right.  So far I know that the first word is "hic."  The context is that there's a marking written in the text between [Luke 23:53 and 23:54](http://www.latinvulgate.com/lv/verse.aspx?t=1&b=3&c=23), and the full page can be seen on page 101 in the (lower-quality) [digital scan](http://webapp1.dlib.indiana.edu/metsnav3/general/index.html#mets=http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.dlib.indiana.edu%2Fiudl%2Fgeneral%2Fmets%2FVAB8631&page=101).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Two remarks: (1) Do you mean 53 and 54 instead of 43 and 44? (2) Margins are too narrow for many interesting things. I'm glad to see other mathematicians here.

Comment: **Hic co^tinua^^** Here continu..    It seems to be a rubric put in for use during a Service.

Comment: It looks like the pre-Vatican II reading for the Wednesday of Holy Week ends at verse 53!  http://catholic-resources.org/Lectionary/Roman_Missal.htm

Comment: There's also a marginal comment at the beginning of Chapter 22, which is the beginning of that reading (it's all of Luke 22 and then Luke 23:1-53).  So that comment may also be relevant (though perhaps harder to read since I don't have a photo and the beginnings of the lines are missing).

Comment: The prior margin comment is on page 98 of the scan, and the relevant text of the Roman Missal is [here](http://www.archive.org/stream/missaleromanumm01churgoog#page/n185/mode/2up)

Comment: In a later margin: p125 (Ca 18 St John) The departure to Gethsemane: 
“Hec cum dixisset ihesus: egressus est cum discipulis suis tra^s (trans) torrentem cedron ubi erat ort^^^: in quem introivit ip^e & discipuli eius.”
It says  **‘Huiusque legitur in refectorio.’** “And of this let it be read in the refectory.” or is that ‘of each.’?

Comment: The note on page 125 also appears to have a paired note telling the reader where to stop on page 127.  That portion of John covers roughly the same material as the portion of Luke we're discussing, and it is exactly the Gospel portion of the Missal for Good Friday.

Comment: Also one in Matthew 26 (which is again the death/burial portion read during holy week) on page 42, but no ending comment there.  Also analogous spot in Mark 14 page 63, no ending comment but some pages are missing in the scan.  That's a pretty clear pattern!

Answer (score 8):

Based on insightful comments from Hugh and a lot of help from a friend, we've now sorted out what it reads:

> hic continuand[i sunt] lectiones in refectori[o].

Note that lectiones is written lco with an abbreviation symbol.  This translates to roughly "Continue reading here in the refectory."

The key point is that this marginal comment is one of six appearing in the gospels all of which indicate that the portion of the gospel concerning the death of Jesus should not be read in the refectory but only in church.  As pointed out by Hugh, there's a very similar comment at the end of the passage in John which is not cut off and reads "Huiusque legitur in refectorio" and one in Matthew reading ""hic ... legendum est in refectorio et omissa passioni domini P.incipiendo est vespere autem sabbati."

Comment: refectori[o] of course.